# How can I avoid empty array useState on first reload?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, expo

Every time I reload the app I get empty useSate Array, but when I save or refresh through the vscode only I can see the result.

**React Native Code**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (users.length > 0) return;
      const q = query(
        collection(db, "favoritFreelancer"),
        where("cid", "==", userUid)
      );
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      const userArray = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (favUser) => {
        onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", favUser.data().lancerID), (user) => {
          userArray.push(user.data());
        });
        setUsers(userArray);
      });
    })();
  }, []);
```

This crate infinity loop

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (users.length > 0) return;
      const q = query(
        collection(db, "favoritFreelancer"),
        where("cid", "==", userUid)
      );
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      const userArray = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (favUser) => {
        onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", favUser.data().lancerID), (user) => {
          userArray.push(user.data());
        });
        setUsers(userArray);
      });
    })();
  }, [users]);
```

mapping the array state

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} className="flex-col w-full">
        {users.map((user) =>
          searchText === "" ? (
            <FreelancerCard
              key={user.uid}
              fullname={user.fullname}
              experience={user.experience}
              stars={user.stars}
              jobs={user.jobs}
              status={user.status}
              categories={user.category}
              contact={user.contact}
              imgUrl={user.profilePic}
            />
          ) : fullname.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ? (
            <FreelancerCard
              key={user.uid}
              fullname={user.fullname}
              experience={user.experience}
              stars={user.stars}
              jobs={user.jobs}
              status={user.status}
              categories={user.category}
              contact={user.contact}
              imgUrl={user.profilePic}
            />
          ) : null
        )}
      </ScrollView>
```

**Firebase Collections**
**Users **Collection
[image]

**favoritFreelancer **Collection
[image]

**When reload the app** => I tried
[image]

**When I save the code** => I expect
[image]
=> this needs to be shown when my app reloaded

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this one

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  getUserData();
},[])

const getUserData = async () => {
  if (users.length > 0) return;
  const q = query(
    collection(db, "favoritFreelancer"),
    where("cid", "==", userUid)
  );
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
}

querySnapshot.forEach(async (favUser) => {
    onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", favUser.data().lancerID), (user) => {
      // If the data is coming in a key value pair 
      setUsers([...users,user.data()]);
      // If the data is not coming in a key value pair
      setUsers([...users,{user.data()}]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured a new way using firebase reference, and I'll posted in 30 mins